# How to arrange matplotlib scatterplot surface data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I am starting with matplotlib and would like to generate a bubble chart. I started with the [the scatter demo](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) but I cannot understand how to prepare my data. My aim is to get this (the surfaces are in proportions 1:2:3:4)

[image]

and my code was

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2]
y = [1, 2]
x_label = ["a", "b"]
y_label = ["x", "y"]
size = [100, 200, 300, 400] # I tried wild combinations here
plt.xticks(x, x_label)
plt.yticks(y, y_label)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=size, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

This generates the following plot (correct axis, two bubbles of relative size 1:2)

[image]

I do not know how to format the data input, `size` should be made up of `len(x)*len(y)` elements but how to arrange them?

Comment: You've only plotted two points; you need `x=[1,1,2,2]` and `y=[1,2,1,2]`.

Comment: (and then replace `x` and `y` in `xticks` and `yticks` with `[1,2]` and `[1,2]`)

Comment: This is it! Thanks. I now understand that I need to generate all the triplets across the three tables (to cover all the combinations). Would you mind copy/paste your comments to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plot command was wrong; you need to specify `x` and `y` for each point you want to plot , so 4 values for both `x` and `y`.

See the [docs for more info](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) (specifically about the shape of x and y)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2,1,2]
y = [1, 1,2,2]
x_label = ["a", "b"]
y_label = ["x", "y"]
size = [100, 200, 300, 400] # I tried wild combinations here
plt.xticks([1,2], x_label)
plt.yticks([1,2], y_label)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=size, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

creates

[image]